# How to print ENV VAR name to file, NOT VALUE from linux cli

Tags: linux, environment-variables, command-line-interface, eof, cat

I have this:

```
cat > ~/add_api_txt_hook.sh <<EOF 
#!/bin/bash 
... 
echo $MY_ENV_VAR
EOF
```

MY_ENV_VAR is not set when this file is made. So it makes it "" in the file.

I want the file contents to be

```
#!/bin/bash 
... 
echo $MY_ENV_VAR
```

NOT:

```
#!/bin/bash 
... 
echo ""
```

How do I print the actual ENV VAR ***KEY*** to the file? I have searched the internet, but it only returns how to print the value to the file.

Tried google and various syntax around the key (), "", {} etc...

Comment: Are you asking about `echo \$MY_ENV_VAR`? With an escape slash.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish this.
Obviously, as SiKing pointed out, you can just backslash-escape the dollar sign.

You can *also* quote the `EOF` itself. While

```
$: cat >x <<EOF
echo $PATH
EOF
```

puts the *value* of `$PATH` (including being empty, as in your case) in the file,

```
$: cat >x <<'EOF'
echo $PATH
EOF
```

does not:

```
$: cat x
echo $PATH
```

Likewise, you can use a "here-string":

```
$: cat <<<'echo $PATH'
echo $PATH
```

But be aware that where a here-doc behaves much the same whether single- or double-quotes are used -

```
$: cat <<"EOF"
echo $PATH
EOF
echo $PATH
```

here-strings differentiate; single-quotes don't expand variables, but doubles do.

```
$: cat <<<"echo $PATH"
echo /c/Users/....(redacted)
```